# ANDROID: what is the best approach with the fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

Before anyone comments I have not found the answer by searching them on the internet on it stak.

Assuming that I want to build an app with products and categories most even considering layout and different orientations.

Do you think is better:

Manage with one more activity screens for categories.

**activityCategory**

fragmentListCategories
 
fragmentDetailsCategories
 
fragmentListCategories (land)
fragmentDetailsCategories (land)

**or**

separate activity.

**activityCategoryDettails** 
fragmentDetailsCategories 
fragmentDetailsCategories (land)

**activityCategoriesList** 
fragmentListCategories 
fragmentDetailsCategories

EDIT

I would add, though I do not think it is relevant that the data are taken from a database

Comment: You didn't search well enough then. [Creating Single-pane and Multi-pane Layouts](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html#Fragments)

Comment: It describes exactly what You asking about, one activity with multiple fragments vs multiple activities and multiple fragments. And the answer is _The approach you choose depends on your design and personal preferences_ mostly the concern is about ActionBar.

Comment: you're right, forgive me I did not read well

Answer (score 0):

First variatn is preferable because you can show list and details together on the tablet.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on fragments behaviour you need.

The first solution could be the best choice if you need to communicate with all **Fragment** using as central node the **activityCategory**, however the other pattern seems to work fine too, in that case is only a architectural matter

Comment: Yes, communication is necessary. the speech is just that there is a better approach over another? also in terms of performance

Comment: So in that case the first solution is still the best, also in terms of perfomance cause you can manage Fragments in a transaction stack using the standard behaviour of Android managing its stack and so also the back button...